# How to concatenate 2 strings using malloc and not the library functions

Tags: c, string-concatenation

I need to create a function to concatenate 2 strings, in my case they are already given. I will need to concatenate the strings 'hello' and 'world!' to make it into 'helloworld!'. However, I can't use library functions besides strlen(). I also need to use malloc. I understand malloc would create n amounts of bytes for memory, however, how would I make it so that it can return a string array if thats possible.

Here is what I have so far,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int *my_strcat(const char* const str1, const char *const str2)
{   
    int s1, s2, s3, i = 0;
    char *a;

    s1 = strlen(str1);
    s2 = strlen(str2);
    s3 = s1 + s2 + 1;

    a = char *malloc(size_t s3);

    for(i = 0; i < s1; i++)
        a[i] = str1[i];

    for(i = 0; i < s2; i++)
        a[i+s1] = str2[i];

    a[i]='\0';

    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n",my_strcat("Hello","world!"));
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me out.

Comment: Returning int * is wrong

Comment: `strlen()` returns `size_t` *not* `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternate fix. First, you forgot `#include <stdlib.h>` for `malloc()`. You return a pointer to `char` from the function `my_strcat()`, so you need to change the function prototype to reflect this. I also changed the `const` declarations so that the pointers are not `const`, only the values that they point to:

```
char * my_strcat(const char *str1, const char *str2);
```

Your call to `malloc()` is incorrectly cast, and there is [no reason to do so anyway in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). It also looks like you were trying to cast the argument in `malloc()` to `size_t`. You can do so, but you have to surround the type identifier with parentheses:

```
a = malloc((size_t) s3);
```

Instead, I have changed the type declaration for `s1, s2, s3, i` to `size_t` since all of these variables are used in the context of string lengths and array indices.

The loops were the most significant change, and the reason that I changed the `const`s in the function prototype. Your loops looked fine, but you can also use pointers for this. You step through the strings by incrementing a pointer, incrementing a counter `i`, and store the value stored there in the `i`th location of `a`. At the end, the index `i` has been incremented to indicate the location one past the last character, and you store a '\0' there. Note that in your original code, the counter `i` was not incremented to indicate the location of the null terminator of the concatenated string, because you reset it when you looped through `str2`. @jpw shows one way of solving this problem.

I changed `main()` just a little. I declared a pointer to `char` to receive the return value from the function call. That way you can `free()` the allocated memory when you are through with it.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * my_strcat(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{   
    size_t s1, s2, s3, i = 0;
    char *a;

    s1 = strlen(str1);
    s2 = strlen(str2);
    s3 = s1+s2+1;
    a = malloc(s3);

    while(*str1 != '\0') {
        a[i] = *str1;
        str1++;
        i++;
    }
    while(*str2 != '\0') {
        a[i] = *str2;
        str2++;
        i++;
    }

    a[i] = '\0';                    // Here i = s1 + s2

    return a;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *str = my_strcat("Hello", "world!");
    printf("%s\n", str);

    /* Always free allocated memory! */
    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always unnecessary and a bad idea.

Comment: @ChrisDodd-- you're right. I was trying to be clear and pedagogical with the OP, who seemed to have some troubles with `malloc()`, but it really wasn't helpful. I have fixed this in my answer.

Comment: Make all those `s`es a `size_t` and you could drop the ugly cast to `s3` when passing it to `malloc()`.

Comment: @alk-- That is a great suggestion. Done. I should have thought of that myself.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is imo a bit simpler with pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *mystrcat(char *a, char *b) {
  char *p, *q, *rtn;
  rtn = q = malloc(strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1);
  for (p = a; (*q = *p) != '\0'; ++p, ++q) {}
  for (p = b; (*q = *p) != '\0'; ++p, ++q) {}
  return rtn;
}

int main(void) {
  char *rtn = mystrcat("Hello ", "world!");
  printf("Returned: %s\n", rtn);
  free(rtn);
  return 0;
}
```

But you can do the same thing with indices:

```
char *mystrcat(char *a, char *b) {
  char *rtn = malloc(strlen(a) + strlen(b) + 1);
  int p, q = 0;
  for (p = 0; (rtn[q] = a[p]) != '\0'; ++p, ++q) {}
  for (p = 0; (rtn[q] = b[p]) != '\0'; ++p, ++q) {}
  return rtn;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Very concise.

Comment: @adabsurdum, Gene
Firstly thanks for a clean & efficient snippet. Quick question. 
Can I call this snippet in this way?
char *rtn = mystrcat("Hello ", "world!");
rtn = mystrcat(rtn, " Good Morning");
// expecting result to be like "Hello world! Good Morning";
will that have any over memory consumption/leakage ?

Comment: Yes if that's all you do. Every call allocates a new buffer for the result.  Two calls require to free()s.  nb: This style where  a function mallocs space for its return value should be avoided if possible. It's a bad pattern exactly because it's so easy to cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

In the return from `malloc` you don't need to do any cast (you had the syntax for the cast wrong anyway) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for more information).

You need to include the header `stdlib.h` for the malloc function.

And most importantly, `a[i]='\0';` in this `i` is not what you need it to be; you want to add the null char at the end which should be `a[s3]='\0';` (the length of s1+s2).

This version should be correct (unless I missed something):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //for malloc
#include <string.h>

char *my_strcat(const char* const str1, const char *const str2)
{
    int s1,s2,s3,i=0;
    char *a;
    s1 = strlen(str1);
    s2 = strlen(str2);
    s3 = s1+s2+1;
    a = malloc(s3);
    for(i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
        a[i] = str1[i];
    }
    for(i = 0; i < s2; i++) {
        a[i+s1] = str2[i];
    }
    a[s3-1] = '\0'; // you need the size of s1 + s2 + 1 here, but - 1 as it is 0-indexed

    return a;
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n",my_strcat("Hello","world!"));
    return 0;    
}
```

Testing with [Ideone](https://ideone.com/7j6URX) renders this output: `Helloworld!`

Comment: Shouldn't the return type be `char *` instead of `int *` ?

Comment: @SandeepTuniki Oh right, missed that. I think you are correct (although it might not matter in this case given that char might be an unsigned int, although I think it is implementation defined)

Comment: Oh, I see. I actually had a bit of trouble understanding how to use malloc tbh. Thanks so much!

Comment: WRONG! This is an off by one error. You should allocate `s3 + 1` because the write of `buffer[s3]` is incorrect.

Comment: @self Is it? Please tell me where? I'm guessing that you mean `a[s3]='\0';` but it already has +1 for the null char. Look at the assignment to `s3`: `s3 = s1+s2+1;`

Comment: 0 indexed. `s3` it should be `s3 - 1` to access the last byte in the buffer. This is a common mistake made when you implement strcat

Comment: Hello, i actually have one other question. I know I put it in the code myself but I totally forgot why.

Comment: How come when I initialised char a, i used char *a?

Comment: What would happen if I did not include it?

Comment: @self I'm tired, brain is working at half speed.... ofc you are right, but with 0 index it should be s3-1 (which I actually had in the first edit of this answer)

Comment: I made this same mistake before when I implemented strcat. If you think about the call to malloc it makes a lot of sense. It's just hard to see

Comment: @joeymed `char a` is a char, `char *a` is a pointer to a char and malloc returns a pointer to a char (in your case).

Comment: @self Yeah, one-off errors is why we love C, isn't it ;) (although they're common enough in other languages too - no need to hate on C) ;)

Comment: Passing `int*` to `printf()` where an `char*` is expected, is passing the wrong type, which in turn provokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @alk oh, I thought I had corrected that in an earlier edit; it's fixed now anyway.